# How to solve the problem: zsh: error on TTY read: unknown error 512?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have a problem with my zsh. It works some time after running in VS code and then fails and blocks bash. The error is: "zsh: error on TTY read: unknown error 512". I reinstalled zsh and ran it once again and then it failed again. Does anyone have any idea how to solve the problem? Thank you!

Comment: `zsh` and `bash` are two different shells. `bash` does not seem to be involved here.

Comment: More information would be needed to understand this. Where and how are you running zsh. Is this running inside VS code? Which OS? Does it work in a normal terminal? What do you mean by "blocks bash".